# Bones parent-child relationship on different axis

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

So I am creating this mechanical arm rig and at the tip theres this grip mechanism that consists of two parts sliding towards each other for the grip to close on something.
Now, in order to make it quicker and easier on me in the animation phase I have gone ahead and added this third bone (number 1 in the image) which controls bones number 2 and 3. 
How do I make it so when I move bone #1 on the X axis, bones #2 and #3 move on the Y axis in and out accordingly?
Hope I make myself clear enough.

[image: grip rig]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a transformation constraint on bones 2 and 3.  Transformation constraints take the transformation of one bone and use it to apply some arbitrary transformation to a different bone.  They're sort a poor man's driver.  (This is also something you could easily do with drivers.  Plenty of other ways too.)

Let's say you want bone B to move 1 unit in the positive X local axis when you move bone A 1 unit in its positive Y local axis.  Create a transformation constraint on bone B.  You want to affect position on both bones, so use "loc" (location) for both bones.  Map Y to X.  Set it to use local space for both bones.  Finally, enter a range of values for input and output; in this case, use 0 to 1 for the source Y and 0 to 1 for the destination X.

For the other side, it's the same constraint, except you want it moving in the opposite direction-- so map the destination to 0 to -1 in the X instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I actually still couldn't get it to work but at least I knew which constraint I was looking for and with the help of youtube I finally got it working ! thanks again

Comment: New problem came up, I forgot to mention both bones 2 and 3 are children of bone 1 and bone 1 is child of another moving robot part so that the entire thing moves together. but when they are children of bone 1 they kind of copy its location unwanted. Unchecked Inherit location, still same thing. it's hard to put it in words so i hope you get the idea.

Comment: @Omni then unparent it, or use a different bone to drive the transformation.  You have to decide what you want to do when you move bone A in its local Y axis: move bones 1 and 2 in the same direction, pinch, or both.  All are possible.